# Is is possible to add HTML tags in velocity template?

Tags: apache-camel, velocity, dsl

I have a template file ie( sample.vm) file . It has some text in it. I want to make the text bold,italic want to add some image to that file and send it to some other sourse . 
My question is how can I beautify that .vm file using html tags or there is some other way to do so?

Comment: How is it even related to Apache Camel? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck at? Consider referring [to this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on framing a good question, to increase your chances of getting some help.

Comment: I am using apache-camel velocity component to send a template message to an email service. As of now i m just sending plain text now I want to add images to that text which is being send to email service and the text which i am sending to an email service is dynamically generated in .vm file.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity can be used to generate any text-based format, and since HTML **is** a text-based format, then yes.

You will then have to tell whatever framework is using the generated files in your architecture than those actually are HTML files.

Comment: When i m using html tags in my .vm file its being send in the same way like if i want to make text bold i am using<b>Hello</b> i want to make hello bold but when i and sending an email in email in m receving <b>Hello</b>. I want Hello to be bold but the html part is not getting rendered.

Comment: I don't know which email sending service you are using, but this service must be made aware of the MIME type you are sending to it (`text/html` rather than `text/plain`), and Velocity can't do it for you.